# Custom implicit conversions in scala play framework forms

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

In some countries there is a comma used as a decimal mark, but implicit conversion in scala play framework forms accepts only dots. So I'd like to add custom string to bigDecimal conversion. I was thinking about something similar to this

```
implicit object StringImplicits {
  implicit def String2Decimal(value: String) = new BigDecimal(value.replace(",", "."))
}
```

But where should I put it to make it work? My form looks like this and it's inside a controller:

```
  val priceForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "fuelPrice" -> bigDecimal(10, 2),
      "totalPrice" -> bigDecimal(10, 2)
    )(priceFormData.apply)(priceFormData.unapply)
```

Comment: An implicit will not help you here. Implicits are resolved at compile-time, so you can't use them to magically apply to certain run-time values. You would need to create a custom `Mapping[BigDecimal]` that can handle both number formats.